# Resize images depending on device

Tags: android, image, replace, rescale

I have created an app with a lot of pictures in `drawable` folder, but putting various sizes of images to all `drawable` folders (ldp,mdp,hdp,xhdp,xxhdp) results in a very large app size. I want to add only one image and resize it depending on the device, and than replace it in my `drawable`.  I use image ID in my other classes.

How can I find out the device density and resize and replace image in `drawable` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use drawable-xxhdpi folder only. Android will scale the images by itself. But it will cause more intensive CPU and memory usage.